# Подключение к БД Firebird от чужой роли.

Tags: firebird

Добрый день, форумчане. Столкнулся с следующей проблемой. Мы используем БД Firebird 2.5, в которой куча ролей и пользователей. При подключении пользователя от чужой роли само подключения почему-то происходит, но при первом же запросе вылетает ошибка о недостаточности прав на таблицу или процедуру например.
Как я сам понимаю, подключение вообще не должно происходить, но почему-то это не так.

Как решить эту проблему?